# How to use uploadConfigurationName and buildConfigurationName

Tags: groovy, gradle

In gradle [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) we can read:

> For each configuration in your project, Gradle provides the tasks *uploadConfigurationName* and *buildConfigurationName* [[18]](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html#ftn.N14FC4).

As I understand I can create build which looks like this (without any plugin because I don't want to use plugins in this project):

```
configurations {
    productSrc
}

// create zip file which will be published
buildProductSrc(type: Copy) << {
    // do the job
}

// publish zip which were build by buildProductSrc
uploadProductSrc {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            url "http://ivy.repo/repo"
        }
    }
}
```

So if I run `gradle buildProductSrc uploadProductSrc` it will build zip and piblish it on ivy repository. Do I understand it correctly becouse it doesn't work?

**[UPDATE]**
According to Peter Niederwieser answer this is a working version of build:

```
apply plugin: 'base'

configurations {
    productSrc
}

// create zip file which will be published
buildProductSrc << { // unable to create specific task, for example 'type: Copy'
    // do the job
}

// publish zip which were build by buildProductSrc
uploadProductSrc {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            url "http://ivy.repo/repo"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note configuration "productSrc" results in "buildProductSrc" and "uploadProductSrc" - the lowercase 'p' in "productSrc" becomes uppercase 'P' in "ProductSrc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `uploadConfigurationName` and `buildConfigurationName` tasks, you'll have to apply the `base` plugin, or a plugin that in turn applies the `base` plugin (`java`, `groovy`, etc.). Alternatively, you can declare and configure such tasks yourself (but it takes more effort).

Comment: Can you also answer how can I control which file built by buildConfigurationName should be published by uploadConfigurationName? For example, during build* task I create 3 files but only one of them should be published.

Comment: The purpose of the `buildConfigurationName` task is to build exactly those artifacts that `uploadConfigurationName` will upload. Artifacts are assigned to configurations in the `artifacts` block.