# gradle build<ConfigurationName>: different packaging for ear and war (gradle v2.3)

Tags: java, gradle, war, ear

I want to use gradle v2.3 configurations to package my application in two ways:

1. **ear** with all libs in *ear's lib directory* and multipe wars inside ear (deps declared with *providedCompile* and *earlib*)
2. **multiple war** files with libs included in each war in *WEB-INF/lib* (deps declared with *compile*)

I can perform each of those two tasks if i modify build.gradle files every time I want different packaging.
I would like to use *configurations* to choose if *jars* are included in *war* files or not by using `gradle build<ConfigurationName>`.

Based on help and [StackOverflow post How to use uploadConfigurationName and buildConfigurationName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939900/how-to-use-uploadconfigurationname-and-buildconfigurationname) I composed the following file (this is for one of the wars):

```
apply plugin: 'war'

configurations {
        packEar
        packWar
    }

dependencies {
    configurations.packEar {
        providedCompile project(':Common') // jars will be included using earlib
    }

    configurations.packWar {
        compile project(':Common') // jars included in war
    }
}

artifacts {
        packWar war
        packEar war
}
```

**The problem is** that commands `gradle buildpackWar` and `gradle buildpackEar` produce *equal* *wars* that do not include *jars* from `Common` project. 
If I change configuration of packEar from `providedCompile` to `compile` both produce war with *jar*s included.

*Additional info:* I tried using `extendFrom compile / providedCompile` but it didnt seem to affect anything. I included `buildpackWar` and `buildpackEar` methods but it didn't work either (might have been that I used those in a wrong way).

Thank you for your answers!

Best regards,
Ziga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the info provided by [Ben Navetta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725688/ben-navetta) I managed to produce a working configuration, it only required a few minor adjustments. Here are the files

**ACL war**

```
apply plugin: 'war'

apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

configurations {
    shareable
    publishedWar // need this so war gets placed in ear instead of jar, 
                 // using archives puts both wars in ear
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile project(':Common');
    shareable project(':Common');
}

war {
    baseName = war.baseName + '-thin'
    classpath = war.classpath
}

task standaloneWar(type: War, dependsOn: war) {
    baseName = project.name  // sharable war's name without modifications
    classpath = war.classpath + configurations.shareable
}

artifacts {
    archives standaloneWar
    publishedWar war // to be included in ear
}
```

Note:

1. if `providedCompile project(':Common');` is omitted this will not
   compile
2. I added *war {...}* so I can rename the war which does not
   contain any of the dependencies and have name of the war which
   contains dependencies without modifications in its name

**EAR**

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

evaluationDependsOn ':ACL' // probably not needed

dependencies {
    deploy project(path: ':ACL', configuration: 'publishedWar')
    earlib project(path: ':ACL', configuration: 'shareable')
}  

ear {
    deploymentDescriptor {  
        webModule ('ACL-thin.war', "${project.name}/ACL") // set context root        
    }
}
```

Note:

1. if **publishedWar** configuration is not applied jar is placed in ear
2. if **archives** is used **both wars** get places in *ear*
3. if you use *eclipse* plugin consider changing `earlib project(path: ':ACL', configuration: 'shareable')` changing to `earlib project(':Common')` or you will have to modify deployment assembly in eclipse (the *war* will be included in *ear's lib* folder in *eclipse*

Answer (score 2):

`compile` and `providedCompile` are configurations of their own, so you're adding the Common project to those, not the `packWar` and `packEar` configurations. Something like this ought to work:

#### Project `mywar`

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    shareable
}

dependencies {
    shareable project(':common')
}

task standaloneWar(type: War, dependsOn: war) {
    baseName = war.baseName + '-standalone'
    classpath = war.classpath + configurations.shareable
}

artifacts {
    archives standaloneWar
}
```

#### Project `myear`

```
apply plugin: 'ear'
apply plugin: 'java'

evaluationDependsOn ':mywar'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    deploy project(':mywar')
    earlib project(path: ':mywar', configuration: 'shareable')
}
```

It will produce three main artifacts:

- `mywar.war`, which does not contain any of the dependencies in `shareable` (like `common`)
- `mywar-standalone.war`, which contains dependencies in `shareable`
- `myear.ear`, which contains `mywar.war` (technically `mywar.jar`) in the root directory and the dependencies from `shareable` in the `mywar` project under `/lib` (such as `common`)